# setting the reverse dns for a email server

Tags: domain-name-system, nameserver, reverse-dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [setting the reverse dns for a email server](https://serverfault.com/questions/265491/setting-the-reverse-dns-for-a-email-server)

I'm having some trouble with email on a dedicated server, with Windows Server 2008. I've reached the conclusion I have to setup reverse dns for the mail server.

The current setup is this:

The mail server is an exchange server rented from a 3rd party company, and is set as MX record in our dns server. The dns server is hosted on a different machine, a dedicated server (Windows Server 2008) under my control.

The question is who needs to set the reverse dns:
1. The company that hosts the email server
2. Me, that controls the dns zone for the domain
3. The company that hosts our name server

I've never really understood who has the authority to set the reverse dns zones... Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are only two people that can set PTR records on public IPs.

1. The owner of the IP address space
2. A delegate of the owner.

If you are renting the server, you need to get in touch with the 3rd party and have them set the correct record.